# Difference between upcoming and forthcoming

Tags: differences

What is the difference between upcoming vs forthcoming?

For example, which one is the correct :

```
Forthcoming Movies OR  Upcoming Movies
```

Comment: Hi Eilia. To be considered a good question, your post should offer proof of your research in dictionaries etc.; and pinpoint exactly which part you need help in. This will likely be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't think of any context where there's any difference in *meaning*<sup>1</sup>, but it may be worth noting that OED's first citation for ***upcoming*** is 1959 (and they say the usage is "chiefly US").

Here's the evidence that the more recent ***upcoming*** has largely displaced earlier ***forthcoming*** (which in consequence might often be perceived as slightly more "formal" as well as "dated")...

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> I mean in the general sense of *due to happen in the future*. Obviously ***forthcoming*** also has another sense - in *I wish you'd be more forthcoming* it means *informative, responsive, open, honest* - where ***upcoming*** can't be substituted.

Comment: @Eilia: Well, it looks like it's about to get closed. I'd have liked to have seen whether one of the real specialists here could tell us more about *why* the newer form became so popular so quickly. I'm open to the possibility that people are influenced by the avoidance of ambiguity and confusion with the *forthcoming = informative* sense, but I think I might take some convincing. People aren't usually bothered by words that have multiple meanings in different contexts.